# Referring to a value in a dropdown list in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, select

I am building validation for my forms. I have covered the input text fields with the folowing code:

```
function validateForm_id()
{
var ctrl = document.forms["form1"]["id"];
var x=ctrl.value;
if (x==null || x=="") {
document.getElementById('id').style.backgroundColor="#FFD4D4";
document.getElementById("id").style.borderColor="#FF7A7A";
document.all.id.innerText = "password required";
```

I would like to validate the value from my select drop down boxes. The values are:

-- Select Title --
Mr
Mrs
Ms

I would like the user to not be able to submit if -- Title -- is the value from the box.

how do i refer to the first value of the dropdownbox in the `if (x==null || x=="")` of the above code? Here is my dropdown:

```
<select name="title" onKeydown="Javascript: if (event.keyCode==13) post();" onFocus="validation_title()" onBlur="return validateForm_title()" id="title">
    <option>- Title -</option>
    <option value="1">Mr</option>
    <option value="2">Mrs</option>
    <option value="3">Ms</option>
    <option value="4">Other</option>
</select> <div align="center" id="title" style="font-size:small; color:#FF0000;"><script type="text/javascript">document.all.title.innerText = " ";</script></div>
```

Comment: `document.all`?! We aren't in the 1990's anymore - nowadays all browsers support `document.getElementById`; besides that you might want to have a look at jQuery - it's much more comfortable.

Comment: yeah sorry i realy suck at javascript haha but it works thanks for the headsup

Comment: Then you should really have a look at jQuery. This not only has the advantage that it saves you some trouble but also the risk of finding really crappy/old examples is low when searching for jQuery code. By the way, `javascript:` doesn't belong in onkeydown etc. attributes - they always contain javascript, the only reason why it doesn't break is that `xyz:` is a label and pretty much a no-op. And I'm pretty sure that your handler will only work in IE since other browser don't use a global event object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `selectedIndex` property of  `<select>` to check out that the first index is never selected.

```
if (ctrl.selectedIndex == 0) { alert('The Title field is required'); }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var select = document.getElementById('mySelectID');
alert(select.options[0].value); //first option's value
alert(select.value); // currently selected value
```

To get option's text use

```
alert(select.options[select.selectedIndex].text);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var opts = yourSelectObj.options;
```

then loop on options.